# Apple watch still paired to an iPhone I no longer have

Tags: bluetooth, apple-watch, apple-watch.app

I used to have an iPhone from work and my Apple watch was paired to it.
Now that I've bought a new iPhone and given back my old iPhone I am unable to pair my apple watch to the new phone.

My Apple watch says: "wrong code, go to Apple Watch app and..."
There is no chance to enter the code manually.

But in the App I can only start to pair a new device, but the watch is still paired.

What steps do I have to do?

My Apple Watch is from series one and I don't know the software version nor how to determine it.

Comment: On your Apple Watch go to Settings > General > About. Once on this screen swipe up until you see the Version. That will tell you what version of watchOS you have installed?

Comment: There is a misunderstanding, I am unable to do anything with my watch. It prompts as soon as I touch it "wrong code, please open the watch app on your iPhone" what I have done now is removing my old iPhone from my iCloud account. My Apple Watch didn't appear in my iCloud account. Not sure if it should.

Comment: When you say *"It prompts as soon as I touch it"* do you mean you get prompted **after** you enter your passcode, or that all you do is literally touch the screen and you get prompted? Can you still access your old iPhone, just to unpair the watch?

Comment: i mean, as soon as i touch it. I can't access the old phone. :(

Comment: Please see my updated answer. All the best!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you can do, assuming you're not worried about losing the data on your Apple Watch, is to erase all content and settings on the watch itself. However, if you have no access to a backup, then you'll be setting the watch up from scratch as a new watch.

If you want to proceed, the process is as follows:

1. Launch the Settings app on your Apple Watch
2. Tap on General
3. Swipe up and tap on the Reset button
4. Tap on Erase All Content and Settings
5. Tap on Erase All

Once complete, your watch will be back to factory settings. You can now go through the process of pairing it with your new iPhone.

**NOTES:**

1. In your situation this is unlikely, but if you're prompted to restore from a watch backup, then select the latest backup you have.
2. Since you're not likely to have an iPhone backup, you’ll just have to set up your Apple Watch as new.

**[UPDATE]**

Since you've clarified in the comments that you can't actually even touch your Apple Watch screen without getting prompted about a wrong code, try these steps instead:

1. Put the Apple Watch on its charger with the power on (so that it's charging) and keep it on charge for all of the following steps!
2. Press and hold the side button (not the Crown) until you see the Power Off slider
3. Press *hard* on the Power Off slider for about a second and then remove your finger
4. Tap on Erase All Content and Settings
5. Tap on Erase All

Once complete, your watch will be back to factory settings. You can now go through the process of pairing it with your new iPhone.

Comment: thank you sir, i will try that as soon as i am back home where my charger is. 16 hours from now :)

Comment: in a similar situation, but don't want to "lose"  the data on the Apple Watch ... just want to pair my watch to a new phone but don't have any access to the old one.

Comment: @nelsonic Do you have any iTunes backups of your old iPhone? If so, that should have some of the Apple Watch data included (how much depends on whether you were making encrypted backups or not).